# Login by ssh , exec one command and i don't want to quit the bash

Tags: shell, ssh, remote

I want to change PS1 when i ssh another centos

```
    strshell = 'PS1="remote!"'
    os.system("ssh -i %s -l%s -p%s %s %s"%(SSH_KEY,SSH_USER,SSH_PORT,des,strshell))
```

ssh quit automatically. I want to stay in this shell.How to achieve it.

I just change another way to do this

```
 tin = ' sudo -i ; export PS1="Remote! \W :"; exec /bin/bash -i'
 os.system("ssh  -i%s -l%s -p%s %s -t%s" % (SSH_KEY, SSH_USER, SSH_PORT, des, tin))
```

but i changed my local machine prompt not the remote one. why?
**os.system is a python function**

Comment: I think to get a shell that you can actually use you'll need to invoke a terminal emulator such as xterm/gnome-terminal/terminator from within that os.system, and then launch your SSH command from within that. Otherwise only your Python program will have access to the `os.system(..ssh..)` process that it launched.

Comment: Have you checked `pexpect`?

Comment: I achieved the same by changing the PS1 setting in the .bashrc of all remote machines I was working on (30+ servers). This means some setup work, but then you can just ssh into the machines..

Answer (score 3):

`sudo -i` runs a login shell as the target user. The rest `export PS1...` would only be executed after that shell has terminated.

Also, your `~/.bashrc` is likely to override PS1 to passing it in the environment will probably not help.

You could try:

```
ssh -t host 'sudo env PROMPT_COMMAND="PS1=\"Remote! \W: \"
             unset PROMPT_COMMAND" bash -l'
```

(assuming the target user's `~/.bashrc` doesn't set `$PROMPT_COMMAND`).

Comment: Yeah,it's right.When i run my script,`export PS1...`would be executed after terminated. Why? can you explain it more details?

Comment: I want to still link to this remote machine after i change PS1, a little confused ...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
ssh -t localhost "echo '. /dev/fd/2'|sudo bash -sil 2<<\FILE        
PS1='my prompt : '
exec 2>/dev/tty
exec </dev/tty
FILE
"
[sudo] password for mikeserv: 
my prompt : id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel),19(log)
my prompt :
```

`sudo` will close all file descriptors but 0,1,2 by default and it wants `<&0` on a terminal for the password, but you can often sneak by with hijacking `stderr`. And it's not gone for good, anyway - practically the first thing I do above is reconnect it to `ssh`'s terminal. More realistically you'd have some actual script that you would pass through like `$(cat file)` where my `$PS1` definition is and the rest. It's a lot of annoying indirection, though; it would be better I think to instead handle that stuff as neccessary in remote profiles.