# SSH into a remote shell, execute a 'source' command, and stay in the remote shell

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

I've got a script, named `s`, on a remote server that activates a virtual environment like this:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

When SSH-ed into the server, I'm able to activate the environment by

```
. s
```

And I SSH into the server as following:

```
ssh -t user@host "cd /path/to/dir ; /bin/bash"
```

In addition to changing the working directory to `/path/to/dir` it would be nice if I could activate the environment right away each time I log into the server. But no matter where I put `. s` into the the SSH command, using `-c` for `/bin/bash` or not, the session always ends immediately.

Comment: is adding it to the user's `.bashrc` an option or should the souring only occur when sshing into the machine?

Comment: I'm afraid it's the latter

Comment: could you use `/bin/bash --rcfile all.rc` in the `ssh` command and in `all.rc` define both the standard `bashrc` and your special `s` sourcing?

Comment: Maybe I could. Haven't done such thing before.

Comment: works for my tests at least.

Comment: Similar to [Login by ssh , exec one command and i don't want to quit the bash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152173)

Comment: @DesmondHume - You can also add a check for an SSH-set environment variable such as `SSH_CONNECTION` into `.bashrc`.  If the variable is set, source the script.  Also, check to be sure there isn't something like `exit 0`  or an `exec` call in the script you're sourcing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a new source file e.g. `/home/user/.rcforssh`

```
 #rc for ssh
 . /home/user/.bashrc
 . /home/user/venv/bin/activate  #or whichever location
```

and log in with

```
ssh -t user@host "cd /path/to/dir ; /bin/bash --rcfile /home/user/.rcforssh"
```

Side note: `source` is not POSIX, while `.` is.

---

UPDATE following discussion specifying OP's needs:

For creating and removing the the modified source file `rcforssh` on the fly, on can use:

```
ssh -t user@host "cd /path/to/dir ; echo '. ~/.bashrc ; . s ; rm rcforssh' > rcforssh ; /bin/bash --rcfile rcforssh"
```

i.e. creating the source file with an `echo` command and adding the removal in said file.

Comment: Can I load the bashrc file from the standard input on the fly so that it all becomes a single command line?

Comment: well, you could add the `cd  /path/to/dir` in the `.rcforssh` source file. If that is what you meant? So you'll only end up with the `bash` command in the `ssh`

Comment: I meant something potentially using `echo` and piping

Comment: Well, guess there is no way to make it one line with this approach

Comment: like in [these](http://linux.icydog.net/ssh/piping.php) examples (especially point 4)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand what you are searching for. Could you give a pseudo example?

Comment: Seems like I made it work with `ssh -t user@host "cd /path/to/dir ; echo '. ~/.bashrc ; . s ; rm rcforssh' > rcforssh ; /bin/bash --rcfile rcforssh"`

Comment: (The point 4 makes the remote shell quit too)

Comment: To wrap this all up, if you put my one-liner into your answer, I will gladly accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26928/discussion-between-fiximan-and-desmond-hume).